# How do you make a HTTPS onCall Cloud Function deployed via Firebase private

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

The [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function) note that:

```
> New HTTP and HTTP callable functions deployed with any Firebase CLI
> lower than version 7.7.0 are private by default and throw HTTP 403
> errors when invoked.
```

This implies that the new default for Firebase HTTP callable functions will now be public which my usage confirms (no longer throws HTTP 403 without credentials).

I prefer to have my HTTP functions be private, can I set this to the old behavior via Firebase now? I don't see anything in the Firebase docs to explain this change in behavior or how to switch between private and public HTTP functions.

I **do** see docs on the Google Cloud side to achieve this, is it safe to just modify this myself?

Eg. If I go to Cloud Console and find that function, I now see "Allow unauthenticated" for that function:

[image]

And if I go into permissions, I see member `allUsers` has been given role `Cloud Functions Invoker`. I think if I remove this it should make it private again but not sure how this would affect the Firebase flows of deploying/running this function.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the Cloud Functions Invoker role is what you want to make changes to.  You can do that by following the [instructions in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation), except to **remove** allUsers instead of add it:

> 1. Go to Google Cloud Console
> 2. Click the checkbox next to the function on which you want to grant access.
> 3. Click Show Info Panel in the top right corner to show the Permissions tab.
> 4. Expand Cloud Functions Invoker
> 5. Delete allUsers using the trash icon
> 6. Click Save.

You will even see in the console for that function, before you make the change:

> This resource is public and can be accessed by anyone on the internet. To remove public access, remove "allUsers" and "allAuthenticatedUsers" from the resource's members.

This should not affect redeployment with the Firebase CLI.  The CLI will not make permission changes to existing functions.

Bear in mind that, with this change, you might have to start thinking about allowing certain service accounts to be able to invoke the function.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by your last paragraph about service accounts? How would this affect service accounts? The plan is to access the https callable via authenticated calls either via js client SDK, via mobile SDKs or potentially via a service account. Am I misunderstanding how authenticated calls will work here?

Comment: OK, so, you don't actually want to do this at all. This would make your function unusable by your app.  Callable functions are gated by Firebase Auth, which is not part of GCP. GCP allUsers means something completely different.  You should simply check in your function if  an authenticated user is present.  Be sure to read over the docs carefully. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: Oh dear I see. I did read through the callable docs but I never saw anything that was as clear as what you just said "Callable functions are gated by Firebase Auth". Thank you!